# Determine class type in R (S3 vs S4)

Tags: r, class

Is there any way to determine if an R object is S3 or S4 class?

For example class(x) just returns the object name but not its type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `isS4(my_object)` to determine whether it is an S4 object.  Additionally, `str` should also tell you (look at the top, starts with "Formal Class ...").

Comment: I get this as output of `str`. `Formal class 'DGEList' [package "edgeR"] with 1 slot`. But `isS4` works.

Comment: @user1436187, "Formal class" means S4.